# Laravel 5.7 search by date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, controller

> Question is: How to search by date and by description? What's my problem? I think it could work but it doesn't work at all.

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $date = $request->get('date');
    $projects = Project::where('description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
      ->orWhere('created_at', '%Y-%m-%d','LIKE', '%'.$date.'%')
      ->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
      ->paginate(10)
      ->withPath('?search=' . $search);

    return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input class="form-control" name="date" type="date" > 
   <input class="form-control" name="search" type="text"/>
   <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
   </div>         
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `->whereDate()` instead of `->where()`

```
$projects = Project::where('description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
   ->whereDate('created_at',$date)
   ->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
   ->paginate(10)
   ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
```

if above not working then try this

```
$projects = Project::where('description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date) {
          $query->whereDate('created_at',$date);
        })
       ->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
       ->paginate(10)
       ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
```

check this [Link 1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)
and this also [Link2](https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **whereDate()**

```
...
->whereDate('created_at', '=', $date)
...
```

and if you want to use **OR** **where** then

```
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date){
    $query->whereDate('created_at', '=', $date);
});
```